# How to automatically update data without refreshing page python flask?

Tags: python, jquery, json, flask

How to automatically update data wihtout refreshing the webpage and add a comment, say if the data keeps increasing - `ON`, otherwise `OFF`?

I get my json data from a URL like this:

```
   @app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
   def data():
        params = {
         'api_key': '{API_KEY}',
         }
        url='https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/yy/yy/'
         r= requests.get(url, params=params, verify=False).content
        return render_template('data.html', time=json.loads(r)['time'])


    html:

    {% block body %}
    <h1>data</h1>
     {% for ON in time %}
       <div>{{ON["time"]}}</div>
     {% endfor %}
```

Comment: you could try to use ajax, which is designed for just this purpose. see [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/). Although it would require that you send a request with javascript. You might try `setinterval`.

Comment: i have tried this 
<script>
$('#time').ready(function() {
    auto.load();
});
setInterval(auto_load, 10000);
</script>

but didnt work

Comment: What does "auto_load" do?

Comment: <div id="time"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("div#time").load('data')
}, 2000);
});
</script>

why is it not updating the data ?

Comment: Read the [docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-load.htm) here. Maybe your url should be '/data' if you have such a page. Also, '2000' is 2 seconds.